# Why set() objects has no .count() method?

Tags: python

All basic sequence, like `tuple`, `string`, `list` has the `.count()` method which return count of elements or substrings for strings which was passed like argument.
But why `set` has no this useful method? Or maybe they has another method like `.count()`?

Comment: An element can appear only once inside a `set`. It does not store duplicates.

Comment: It'd always return either 0 or 1, and that information is already given by `thing in my_set`.

Comment: @VedangMehta oh shure, that the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets can't contain duplicates, so the count of any element in the set would always be either 1 or 0.  You can get the same information just by checking `item in some_set`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because sets do not contain duplicates *and* because Python provides the `in` syntax.

In other languages which do not have `in`, like for instance `c++`, the set 
 comes with a `count` method which only returns 0 or 1.